# A question on linear recurrence

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $(a_{i})$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers given by a linear recurrence $a_{i+n}=c_{n}a_{i+n-1}+\dots +c_{1}a_{i}$ with $c_{i}\in\{-1,0,1\}$ and $a_{i}=2^{i}$ for $i=1,\dots n$ such that the characteristic polynomial $p(x)=-x^{n}+c_{n}x^{n-1}+\dots +c_{1}x^{0}$ has a unique dominating real root $\alpha> 1$. Let $(s_{i})\in\{-1,0,1\}^{m}$ with $m\ge n$. 
Is it true that
$\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_{i}a_{i}=0$ 
if and only if $p$ divides the polynomial $\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_{i}x^{i}$? Where I can find a proof of this kind of result?

Comment: I eddited the question according to the answers below.

Comment: It's still not true, and the first degree 3 example I tried ($-p=x^3-x^2-1$ so the sequence is 1,2,4,5 and $s_1=s_4=+1,s_2=s_3=-1$) is a counterexample.  I don't know if one can salvage a reasonable question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what "dominating" means so perhaps this isn't a counterexample, but how about $-p(x)=x^5 - x^4 - x^3 - x^2 + x + 1=(x^2-x-1)(x^3-1)$ (which has a unique real root greater than 1), with $a_1,...,a_5=1,2,3,5,8$ and $s_1=s_2=-1$ and $s_3=1$ giving $\sum s_ix^i=x^3-x^2-x$?

Comment: Ok, let us assume that the inital values are choose, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}a_{i}\not=0$ if $s_{i}$ is not given by the charakteritisc polynimial.

Answer (score 3):

One direction is true (even without $\alpha>1$).

The other directions seems to be wrong. Take the recurrence
$$-a_i+a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}+a_{i-3}=0$$
with initial conditions $a_0=a_1=a_2=1$. Then $p(x)=-x^3+x^2+x+1$ has a "dominating" real root $\alpha=1.839\dots$. I am not clear about what dominating means but $\alpha$ is bigger (in magnitude) than the modulus of the other (complex) roots.

It is clear that $-a_5+a_4+a_3+a_1=0$ as well, the corresponding polynomial is $Q(x)=-x^5+x^4+x^2+1$. But, $p(x)$ does not divide $Q(x)$.

If you must insist strict monotonicity, then consider the below example.
$$-a_i+a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}-a_{i-3}+a_{i-4}=0$$
with initial conditions $a_j=j$ for $j=0,1,2,3$. The sequence begins with $0,1,2,3,4,6,9,14,\dots$. Now, take $-a_7+a_6+a_5-a_1=0$. But, $P(x)=-x^4+x^3+x^2-x+1$ has a root $\alpha=1.512\dots$ and yet $P(x)$ does not divide $$Q(x)=-x^7+x^6+x^5-x=-x(x-1)(x^5-x^3-x^2-x-1).$$

Comment: I don't know if your $a_i$ are "increasing", maybe the OP can clarify?

Comment: Let us assume that the initial values are increasing.

Comment: Thanks for the example. What's if the initial values are exponetialy increasing $a_{i}=2^{i}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: You should decide what you're asking and then edit the question, making it clear that the question has been edited (so that the answers don't look absurd). Or mark this question as answered and then ask a new one.